# Google Map - Find list of postal codes with in the given radius from the given point

Tags: php, google-maps

Can any one please let me know, i need to get the **list of postal codes(UK)** from google map API within a particular radius from the given point(postal code).

I need this to be implement it on PHP with Google Map API.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with Google Maps API.

Comment: I need the same solution. @VAC-Prabhu are u complete this, please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with the Google Maps API I believe unless you have a list of postal codes to check. Take a look at [this API](http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api.php).